# error when create shortcode for plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I already made a plugin myself with custome table but now I want to create short code for it. But
I don't know how to fetch data from mysql (custom table Table name **wp_sitemap**).
I tried to make sample output but I got every time error

I want to display mysql table data but I got 
output like (Table format)

Name -  $row->name

Email - $row->email

```
function viewall() 
{       
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_sitemap");
    $sitemap = '
    <table width=880 border=1>';
    foreach($result as $row)
    { 
$sitemap .= '<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>
    $row->name
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>
    $row->email
    </td>
  </tr>';
  } 
$sitemap .= '</table>';
return $sitemap;
}
add_shortcode('viewall2', 'viewall');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to modify your `$sitemap` variable

```
$sitemap .= '<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>'.
    ($row->name).'
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>'.
    ($row->email).'
    </td>
  </tr>';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,

```
function viewall() {       
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_sitemap", ARRAY_A); // get results as array
    $sitemap = '
    <table width=880 border=1>';
    foreach($result as $row)
    { 
$sitemap .= '<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>'.
    $row['name'].'
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>
    '.$row['email'].'
    </td>
  </tr>';
  } 
$sitemap .= '</table>';
return $sitemap;
```

}

Comment: see OP question he want to display `Name - $row->name` so how would be `$row['name']`

Comment: my problem is solved by satish's answer anyway thank you Vidhu for time:)